# One embedded Token for multiple visuals or pbi reports (pbi embedded)?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Do you know if i can use one generated token for embed multiple visuals or reports from diferent workspaces in the same pbi account? I am using pbi embedded (app owns data). I want to use just one generated token, is it posible?

Answer (score 2):

To embed multiple reports / visuals using single embed token, you can use multi-resource embed token. Using that, A token can be generated that can be used for multiple reports, datasets and target workspaces.

You need to make POST request to https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken with request body which contains, datasets, reports and workspaces.

This API is only supported for App owns data scenario.

Please refer:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/embed-token-generate-token
- https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples (these samples use the multi-resource embed token to embed reports)